# 'Invalid Host header' at http://localhost:3000 when using Flask for the backend and React for the frontend

Tags: reactjs, flask, amazon-ec2, cors

I have been trying to setup a web page for a personal project where I use Flask for the backend and React for the frontend. I can get my Flask app to run at http://website.com:5000 and React to run at http://website.com:3000 seperately. However, when I try to get a value from the backend to display the http://website.com:3000 the webpage shows 'Invalid Host header.' I'm running both Flask and React on an EC2 instance. I've tried using CORS and adding a proxy to my .json file, but neither have worked. React is new to me and I have struggled any resources how to integrate Flask, React, and EC2 together.

Here is the Flask .py code:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='frontend/build')
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)

class HelloApiHandler(Resource):
    def get(self):
        message = "Hello, World!"  # Replace with your desired variable
        return jsonify(message=message)

api.add_resource(HelloApiHandler, '/flask/hello')

@app.route("/", defaults={'path': ''})
def serve(path):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

The React .js code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [getMessage, setGetMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/flask/hello')
      .then(response => {
        console.log("SUCCESS", response);
        setGetMessage(response.data.message);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>React + Flask Tutorial</p>
        {getMessage ? (
          <h3>{getMessage}</h3>
        ) : (
          <h3>LOADING</h3>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the .json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "version",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://website.com:5000/",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm guessing I am still not using CORS currently or am referencing the wrong port somewhere.

Looking at threads from others that have had this issue with 'Invalid Host header' showing up, it seems adding the use of CORS or the proxy in the .json file can help, but has not worked for me.